# Float div to bottom right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no problem floating the div to top right side, but how do I do the same but to the bottom?

Test object: http://jsfiddle.net/wQbB3/

```
.panel-2col-stacked {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-top, .panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-bottom {
  clear: none !important;
  width: auto;
}
.panel-col-top {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

So I need to float the `.panel-col-top` div.

Note that I cannot change HTML structure in the systems core, so the divs and containers has to be exactly the same as in the example above. So I guess this is just a CSS question or JS is welcome too. I can replace/switch the panel-col-top content with panel-col-bottom if needed though.

Some Photoshop skills:
[image]

Should be something like:
[image]

JS solutions are welcome.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What are you attempting to do exactly??? where do you want to float the `panel-col-top` div??

Comment: But I included jsfiddle link. Just check the link in the post. I want the image div to be at the bottom right, not top.

Comment: There is no pure-CSS solution to this, because floats are always on the same top line as their neighbouring elements, and are therefore aligned to the top vertically. There are JS-based solutions, tho.

Comment: Please share the JS solutions then.

Comment: For merging the text you need to have the text and image div in same container.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't have to be an image in the second div. It can be any type of content, not just image. So that's why separate divs.

Comment: This can be done easily if you manage the html so that the last paragraph to float left and image to float right....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**html**

```
<div class="panel-2col-stacked clearfix panel-display">

    <div class="panel-col-bottom panel-panel">
        <p>Sed eget lectus sagittis, tincidunt tortor eget, varius dolor. Maecenas aliquet venenatis vehicula. Praesent ullamcorper luctus purus, eu gravida odio fringilla a. Fusce id risus eu eros interdum pulvinar. Donec rhoncus felis vel tellus ullamcorper; id auctor nunc porta. Fusce sollicitudin elit rhoncus fermentum vulputate! In consequat massa at augue tempus vehicula. Mauris eu purus nec neque hendrerit pretium? Nunc in ante ultricies, pharetra lectus at, vulputate orci.</p>
<p>Nulla blandit nulla nec risus commodo, sit amet volutpat dui aliquet. Donec dapibus et sem in imperdiet? Praesent non risus tortor? Praesent ut libero non ante lacinia tristique! Sed non porttitor velit, sit amet eleifend felis. Cras ultricies risus sem, non interdum enim ultricies quis. Nulla nec odio semper, cursus lorem ac, scelerisque lacus. Morbi in augue est. Aenean accumsan ligula a nulla egestas lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus nec semper metus, volutpat posuere dolor. Quisque id condimentum dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-col-top panel-panel">
        <img width="333" height="233" alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/OUYtEbj.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.panel-2col-stacked {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-top, .panel-2col-stacked .panel-col-bottom {
  clear: none !important;
  width: auto;
}
.panel-col-top {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQbB3/2/)

Change a bit with jquery approach:

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $(".panel-col-top").appendTo(".panel-col-bottom p:nth-child(1)");

});
```

[fiddle jquery approach](http://jsfiddle.net/wQbB3/12/)

After some research i ended with this using prepend():

**js**

```
$(function(){
    var a = $(".panel-col-top");

    $(".panel-col-bottom p:nth-child(2)").prepend(a);
});
```

[fiddle with .prepend() approach](http://jsfiddle.net/wQbB3/15/)

Comment: Text should merge to the side of the image div. I achieved that by just replacing content in both divs and giving bottom div float. Also you moved the panel-col-top out of main container. I mentioned in the post I cannot edit HTML structure.

Comment: That js solution looks great, but what about if it could be at the very bottom with no text below, but only in the side?

Comment: Then use this $(".panel-col-top").appendTo(".panel-col-bottom");

Comment: But text doesn't merge to the side then.

Comment: Can't understand what you mean:)

Comment: Like its shown in the images in the question, text has to merge to the side of the image, check the images. With your solution there's still three lines of text below the image and with that other solution it moves all text above the image div.

Comment: I think if you remove margin: 0 0 0 25px; from .panel-col-top class will be ok.

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: Please try my last approach with .prepend()

Comment: None of this works, just like explained in Terry's comment under original question.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML and CSS, the best way to do that is using 2 paragraphs and the `align` img attribute.

HTML:

```
<p>Sed eget lectus sagittis, tincidunt tortor eget, varius dolor. Maecenas aliquet venenatis vehicula. Praesent ullamcorper luctus purus, eu gravida odio fringilla a. Fusce id risus eu eros interdum pulvinar. Donec rhoncus felis vel tellus ullamcorper; id auctor nunc porta. Fusce sollicitudin elit rhoncus fermentum vulputate! In consequat massa at augue tempus vehicula. Mauris eu purus nec neque hendrerit pretium? Nunc in ante ultricies, pharetra lectus at, vulputate orci.</p>
<p><img width="333" height="233" alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/OUYtEbj.jpg" align="right">Nulla blandit nulla nec risus commodo, sit amet volutpat dui aliquet. Donec dapibus et sem in imperdiet? Praesent non risus tortor? Praesent ut libero non ante lacinia tristique! Sed non porttitor velit, sit amet eleifend felis. Cras ultricies risus sem, non interdum enim ultricies quis. Nulla nec odio semper, cursus lorem ac, scelerisque lacus. Morbi in augue est. Aenean accumsan ligula a nulla egestas lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus nec semper metus, volutpat posuere dolor. Quisque id condimentum dolor.</p>
```

I updated the JS Fiddle. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wQbB3/6/

Here's some JS libraries to wrap text around an image:

- jqSlickWrap: http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/
- bacon: http://baconforme.com/

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I cannot edit structure of the HTML of this CMS and it doesn't have to be just only img, it can be any type of content, so that's why two separate divs, one with text and other in this case with img, but it could be anything in that other div, not just img.

Comment: Yep so it can't be done using HTML and CSS (unless you rely on CSS Floats and a custom HTML structure).

If you can use canvas, there's several tutorials to wrap text in a container:
- http://sourcoder.blogspot.com/2012/12/text-wrapping-in-html-canvas.html
- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/

But you still need to use a custom HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
// test this code
 .panel-2col-stacked {
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
}
.panel-col-top {
     position: absolute;
     right: 33px;
     top: 41px;
 }
 .panel-col-bottom.panel-panel {
     height: 300px;
}
.panel-col-bottom.panel-panel p:last-child {
    padding-right: 400px;
 }
```

Comment: Giving absolute position image overrides the text and text is being hidden under it and not readable.